# MYSQL select where timestamp data not retrieve

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cheque_data` (
`auto_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`job_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`client_id` text NOT NULL,
`ch_no` text NOT NULL,
`ch_date` date NOT NULL,
`ch_bank` text NOT NULL,
`ch_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`sync` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`auto_no`)
 )
```

When I run SQL command in PHPMYADMIN it will retrieve row;

```
SELECT * FROM `cheque_data` WHERE timestamp='2014-03-10 19:37:31'.
```

But in PHP,

```
$sql = "select * from `cheque_data` where timestamp = '2014-03-10 19:37:31'";
$result_remote = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_remote);
echo $row_count; //no data
```

It doesn't give any data. But when I change timestamp to other column, it works.

```
$sql = "select * from `cheque_data` where auto_no = '1'";
$result_remote = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_remote);
echo $row_count; //data found
```

I want to know, what is the reason for this issue?
It is only not working with where timestamp

Thank you,
Sameera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add backticks(`) around timestamp field, as it is reserved word or use this query

```
$sql = "select * from `cheque_data` where `timestamp` = '2014-03-10 19:37:31'";
```

Comment: in this case it is fine NOT to use backticks

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the problem in your `PHP` script, not `MySQL`.
P.S. keep in mind, that it is better to wrap column names in `` ` `` not to confuse MySQL. In your statement it is okay, but fyi there is a function called `TIMESTAMP()`, and in some cases MySQL may think of a non-wraped `column name` as of a `function name`.